# I cannot access App_Code and it is read only

Tags: c#, razor, app-code

I am trying to run some functions and helpers in App_Code folder.

But the folder becomes read-only automatically and I am not able to access any of its functions or helpers from other pages.

Visa Studio 2017 and it is a Web Site Project

Comment: Is your code hosted in any kind of source code management tool like TFS or GIT ?

Comment: how could I find it out? I dont know honestly

Comment: You don't know if you're using source control? If you don't know, then you need to stop and question everything about what you're doing. Learning to use source control is fundamental to doing any sort of software development.

Comment: @arashtrip - is there a lock icon just before the folder/file name in solution explorer in Visual Studio ?

Comment: No there is no lock icon

Comment: " access any of its functions or helpers from other pages" ?? Can you elaborate more on this ? what exactly are you trying to do ?

Comment: very simple. there are two files in the folder: funcions.cshtml and helpers.cshtml. The first one contains some functions and the second contains some helpers. But when I try to call them from the other pages in the project, I receive an error that the function or helper does not exist in this context and another error says that the files are in a App_Code folder which is a special directory. When I disable the read only feature of the folder, the problem goes away but again the folder becomes read-only.